# removeFromSuperview only removes view from last cell

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a UITableView set up with  a custom delete button which consists of a UIButton (btnDel) added as a subview to the UITableView's cells. The delete button is added as a subview when my edit button is pressed. This works well but when I try to remove the subview using:

> [btnDel removeFromSuperview];

It only removes the button from the last cell and the other cells still retain the now removed button. I've tried this in many different ways and still can't figure it out. I've tried using functions such as turning the opacity of the button to 0 or setting Hidden to YES, but like the removeFromSuperview, it only effects the button in the last cell with the others staying the same.

Any help is greatly appreciated and if anymore of my code is needed let me know.

Comment: How do you call the line `[btnDel removeFromSuperview];`? You call on `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: Difficult to answer without seeing the code.  From your description, it sounds like you have only a reference to the last delete button that you created.  Accordingly, [btnDel removeFromSuperview] is only going to act on the last button created.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't keep references you can't tell which button belongs to which cell.
You might want to subclass UITableViewCell so that your cells have a property which points to the button (assign the button to the property right after instantiating the button). You could then use this property to access (enable, disable...) the buttons later on.